# How to implement a dyadic product in a pandaic way

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have the following DataFrame:

```
df    
    A   B
0   2.5 0.1
1   NaN 0.5
2   NaN 0.3
3   2.0 0.1
```

I want to multiply each of the non values in A, with the column B. 
This can be achieved using

```
dyadic = np.multiply(df['A'].values.reshape((1,4)).T, df['B'].values.reshape((1,4)))
dyadic
```

and returns the dyadic product of the vectors

```
array([[ 0.25,  1.25,  0.75,  0.25],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [ 0.2 ,  1.  ,  0.6 ,  0.2 ]])
```

Is it possible to construct a DataFrame like this from pandas directly?

Background to this questions: After a groupby, Every group consists of a DataFrame with the structure above. There is always at least one non-nan entry in A, but there might be multiple. I want to construct a new column as the average of the vectors of (non-nan(A) * (B)) (this is some kind of imputation if you want, taking insecurity of the values of A into account)
which can be achieved simply with

```
np.nanmean(dyadic, axis=0)
array([ 0.225,  1.125,  0.675,  0.225])
```

Or is numpy simply the most elegant solution here?

Comment: Not a Pandas answer but wouldn't `np.outer` (cf https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.4/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) be simpler than your `np.multiply` approach and get the same results?

Comment: Yes, dot is indeed easier. Don't know why I didn't use it. Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AKA, `dot` product.

```
i = df[['A']].values
j = df[['B']].values.T
```

```
i.dot(j)

array([[ 0.25,  1.25,  0.75,  0.25],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [  nan,   nan,   nan,   nan],
       [ 0.2 ,  1.  ,  0.6 ,  0.2 ]])
```

If you want the result as a DataFrame, do this -

```
df[['A']].dot(df[['B']].values.T)
```

Or,

```
df[['A']].dot(df['B'].values[None, :])  # thanks to Zero for the alt
```

```
      0     1     2     3
0  0.25  1.25  0.75  0.25
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  0.20  1.00  0.60  0.20
```

You can then call `mean` or `nanmean` on the result -

```
df[['A']].dot(df[['B']].values.T).mean(0)

0    0.225
1    1.125
2    0.675
3    0.225
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Also as `df[['A']].dot(df['B'].values[None, :])` or `df.A.values[:, None].dot(df.B.values[None, :])`

Comment: @Zero Thanks, added.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried to use dot but somehow wasn't able to get it going

Answer (score 4):

One way

```
pd.DataFrame(columns=df.B,index=df.A).apply(lambda x : x.name*x.index)
Out[93]: 
B      0.1   0.5   0.3   0.1
A                           
 2.5  0.25  1.25  0.75  0.25
NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
NaN    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
 2.0  0.20  1.00  0.60  0.20
```

Another way (should be fast than the `apply`)

```
df[['B']].T.reindex(list(df[['B']])*len(df)).reset_index(drop=True).mul(df.A,0)
Out[106]: 
      0     1     2     3
0  0.25  1.25  0.75  0.25
1   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
3  0.20  1.00  0.60  0.20
```

Comment: See my answer for faster alternative ;-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yeah i thought about it since he want from pandas..haha

Comment: You might be forgetting that pandas has `pd.DataFrame.dot` that could be used.  So `dot` is pandas.